# Callbacks inside a loop : how to know when all is finished?

Tags: android, loops, callback

In a loop, I need to call multiple times a method with callback . How can I know when all is finished ?

```
@Override
public void onObjectsMustBeParsed(String parsableObjects) {
    String[] parsedObjects = parsableObjects.split(",");

    for (String parsedObject : parsedObjects){

        loadObject(parsedObject, new LoadObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onObjectLoaded(Object object) {
                //Object Loaded
                saveObject(object, new SaveObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onObjectSaved() {
                        // Object saved
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // Object not saved

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                // Object not Loaded

            }
        });
    }
}


// => do something when all processing of parsed-objects are finished
       // do something if all is ok
       // do other thing if partially ok
```

Note : To manipulate my data, I use a repository with local and remote data sources. This piece of code is a part of repository.

Comment: Add a volatile integer which indicates the amount of running tasks. Increment when you start a task. Decrement in onObjectLoaded or in onObjectSaved. Then after every decrement check if the task counter is nul.

Comment: @greenapps Ouah pretty cool solution ! But I'm not sure I understood everything with my level of coding. I did not know volatile integer. And you say "Then after every decrement", yes sure but how ?

Comment: @greenapps Do you mean "after every decrement check" in each callbacks ?

Comment: `parsedObjects.length` will give you the total number of objects, why don't you decrement the total in `onError()` then compare the values?

Comment: Indeed in each callback you should have `taskcounter--; if(taskcounter==0) finishedtask();`.

Comment: @greenapps ok good, thank you very much ! i will try to write the answer myself ^^

Comment: @greenapps Nice, your answer works ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a volatile integer which indicates the amount of running tasks. Increment when you start a task. Decrement in onObjectLoaded or in onObjectSaved. Then after every decrement check if the task counter is nul.

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach to the comments, but using an AtomicInteger instead:

```
 AtomicInteger countDownLatch = null;

   @Override
   public void onObjectsMustBeParsed(String parsableObjects) {
      String[] parsedObjects = parsableObjects.split(",");

      countDownLatch = new AtomicInteger(parsedObjects.length);
      for (String parsedObject : parsedObjects){

         loadObject(parsedObject, new LoadObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onObjectLoaded(Object object) {
               //Object Loaded
               saveObject(object, new SaveObjectCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onObjectSaved() {
                     // Object saved
                     int value = countDownLatch.decrementAndGet();
                     if ( value == 0 ) {
                        // we are done
                     }

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError() {
                     // Object not saved
                     int value = countDownLatch.decrementAndGet();
                     if ( value == 0 ) {
                        // we are done
                     }
                  }
               });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
               // Object not Loaded

            }
         });
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative !

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct but I went ahead and created a construct that abstracts all these stuff. It is called MultiTriggerBomb

We can set it up like below
// Create a bomb.

```
multiTriggerBomb = MultiTriggerBomb(5, timerDuration) {
   // Code that needs to get fired on explosion
}
```

Plant the bomb
// plant it!

```
multiTriggerBomb?.plant()
```

Then whenever the your callback is finished. Call down

```
multiTriggerBomb?.down("some condition satisfied")
```

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-prevent-code-execution-till-all-triggers-are-down-or-timer-is-expired-989248849392